# How to distinguish between the setter method and the getter method when using macros in Objc？

Tags: ios, objective-c

Inside the method testUser

```
#define TESTMacro [TestClass shared].testProperty
@interface TestClass:NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString* testProperty;
+ (TestClass*)shared;
@end

@implementation TestClass
+(TestClass *)shared{
    static TestClass *shared = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        shared = [[TestClass alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}
-(void)testUser{
    
    
    TESTMacro = @"1"; //setter
    
    NSString *result = TESTMacro;//getter
}
@end
```

For some reasons, I can't override the setter and getter, so I plan to judge in the macro, and then do different things.But don't know how.

Comment: Could you be more precise when you say I can’t override setter and getter ?

Comment: Add with category another property and use it in the marco.